# Codeception coverage report 0% though the test runs

Tags: yii2, code-coverage, codeception

I cannot set up the code coverage configuration, the report is always 0%. I'm using codeception coverage with two projects, the first one with:

- Yii2
- WebDriver module

Weird stuff:

- I have two codeception.yml:

  - /tests/codeception.yml
  - /codeception.yml
- c3.php is not in root. It is on /vendor/codeception/codeception/tests/data/claypit/c3.php
- I'm not sure where I have to include c3.php

Like I'm not sure which codeception.yml is the right file, I have the same configuration on both files.

```
actor: Tester
paths:
    tests: tests
    log: tests/_output
    data: tests/_data
    helpers: tests/_support
settings:
    bootstrap: _bootstrap.php
    colors: false
    memory_limit: 1024M
modules:
    config:
        coverage:
            enabled: true
            remote: false
            include:
                - /controllers/*
            c3_url: 'http://127.0.0.1/tmsO/#/'
```

I have the same problem with the second project, the differences are that I'm using:

- Yii1
- PhpBrowser module
- Asserts module
- REST module

Thank you in advance. I really need help.

Answer (score 1):

When you use Codeception for acceptance Tests and using PHPBrowser/WebDriver you need remote coverage (`remote: true`). Therefore it will always say 0% in the console but will be saved in the _output directory.

On the remote site, the c3.php will collect all the needed data. So you need to include it in every call to your application. (for more information see https://github.com/Codeception/c3).

You can find the documentation for setting up the code coverage here: http://codeception.com/docs/11-Codecoverage